# calling the wcf service POST from the android

Tags: android, web-services, wcf-data-services

my url is 
http://example.com/WcfService/MasterService.svc

method name is "SearchOrganizations";

String url = URL1 + "/" + METHOD_NAME_SEARCH_ORGANIZATION + "/";

so my url will be **http://example.com/WcfService/MasterService.svc/SearchOrganizations/**

service type is POST. here is my code to call this service from android

```
JSONObject jsonObjSend = new JSONObject();
        try {
            jsonObjSend.put("data", params[0]);
            jsonObjSend.put("CurrentUserId", params[1]);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        List<NameValuePair> paramswithkey = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        paramswithkey.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data", params[0]));
        paramswithkey
                .add(new BasicNameValuePair("CurrentUserId", params[1]));
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPostRequest = new HttpPost(url);

        // httpPostRequest.setHeader("Accept", "application/soap+xml");
        httpPostRequest.setHeader("Content-Type",
                "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8");
        UrlEncodedFormEntity se = null;
        try {
            // se = new StringEntity(jsonObjSend.toString());
            se = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(/*
                                         * jsonObjSend.toString().getBytes(
                                         * "UTF8")
                                         */paramswithkey);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        httpPostRequest.setEntity(se);
        HttpResponse response = null;
        try {
            response = client.execute(httpPostRequest);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Please check your internet connection",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        logI("BEFOR response METHOD_NAME_SEARCH_ORGANIZATION :" + response);
        BasicResponseHandler responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        String strResponse = null;
        if (response != null) {
            try {
                strResponse = responseHandler.handleResponse(response);
            } catch (HttpResponseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        logI("AFTER response METHOD_NAME_SEARCH_ORGANIZATION :"
                + strResponse);
```

I have used this code using the JsonObject as well as NameValuePair but i am getting the exception of following

```
 org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Cannot process the message because the content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8' was not the expected type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'.
```

.Net side they have called the service using the **x-www-form-urlencoded** but i am getting the expected type should be **text/xml; charset=utf-8**

How could i manage to call the POST service.
I have tried with the different ways to call this service but failed to get the response

http://lukencode.com/2010/04/27/calling-web-services-in-android-using-httpclient/

but i couldn't be able to get the response.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My code is also working fine but there is a problem of url from the webservice side that was given to me.

```
http://example.com/WcfService/MasterService.svc/web/SearchOrganizations/
```

Thanks for helping me user1621629...

Answer (score 1):

Try with below code snipt it is working perfact in WCF case. Pass Your parameters in namevalue pair to method and you will get string responce from method. Yes check all permisions before test this snipt as you need add intetn

```
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", name));

public static String postRequest(String url, List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs) {
        String getServerPath = Utils.SERVER_ADDRESS + "methodname";
        String result = null;

        try {
            Log.e("TAG", "url:: " + url);
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

            for (NameValuePair nvp : nameValuePairs) {
                String name = nvp.getName();
                String value = nvp.getValue();
                jsonObject.accumulate(name, value);
                Log.e("TAG", name + "=" + value);
            }
            HttpClient HC = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(jsonObject.toString());
            se.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
            post.setEntity(se);
            HttpResponse res = HC.execute(post);
            HttpEntity entity = res.getEntity();
            result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
            Log.e("TAG", "result:: " + result);
            return result;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

    }
```

Comment: check your webservices with chrome post client.

Comment: in chrome postman i got the same response in which i got in my question. But using your code i couldn't be able to get any response

Comment: Yo. You need to check with your web-service developer. As code from Android is perfect working.